# simple Flickr application with Knockout.js doesn't work (JSBin prepared)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, coffeescript

Now I'm writing a simple application which get five photos from Flickr and display the titles as list. At first I tried `@current_photos` and this works good, but when I use Knockout.js(`@currentPhotos`), this doesn't work.

```
root = exports ? this
class root.Flickr
  constructor: ->
    @photos = []
    $.getJSON(
      'http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?jsoncallback=?'
        format : 'json'
        method : 'flickr.photos.search'
        api_key : '7965a8bc5a2a88908e8321f3f56c80ea'
        user_id : '29242822@N00'
        per_page : 5
    ).done((data) =>
      $.each data.photos.photo, (i, item) =>
        @photos.push item
    )

root = exports ? this
class root.PhotoListViewModel
  index = null
  currentPhotos = []
  constructor: ->
    flickr = new Flickr
    # @current_photos = flickr.photos ###### WORKS GOOD
    flickr.photos = ko.observableArray []
    @currentPhotos = ko.computed ->
      flickr.photos
```

HTML is as below:

```
<body>

<h4>Photo List</h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach: currentPhotos">
    <li>
      title: <span data-bind="text: title"> </span>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
```

I created JSBin page as below:
http://jsbin.com/avazak/7/

Thanks for your kindness.

Comment: you really have to pass a function to ko.computed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of how the [dependency tracking](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) works in computed observable:

> While your evaluator function is running, KO keeps a log of any observables (or computed observables) that your evaluator reads the value of.

So you need to **call** your observables inside the computed it is not enough the reference them:

```
@currentPhotos = ko.computed ->
    flickr.photos()
```

And I would suggets that you declare the `@photos` as `ko.observableArray` inside the `Flickr` object not in the `PhotoListViewModel`

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cq5Nf/).

Comment: Thank you very much! I wrote a little changed code here:http://jsbin.com/avazak/16/edit